The Etale Cohomology from the Variety to its Generic Point
Let $n\in \mathbb{Z}_{>0}$ and $X$ be a smooth projective variety over $k$, where $k$ contains all $n$-th roots of unity and $\mathrm{char}(k)=p$. Here $p$ and $n$ are coprime. I wonder whether the following map is injective:
$$f: H^{1}_{\acute{e}t }(X, \mu_{n})\to H^{1}_{\acute{e}t}(K(X), \mu_{n})$$
where $K(X)$ is the function field of $X$, $\mu_{n}$ is the $n$-th cyclic group and the morphism is induced by $\mathrm{Spec}K(X)\to X$.
By applying the $0\to \mu_{n}\to \mathbb{G}_{m}\to \mathbb{G}_{m}\to 0$ to $X$ and $K(X)$, we can get
$0\to \Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*}/\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*n}\to  H^{1}_{\acute{e}t}(X, \mu_{n})\to \mathrm{Pic}(X)[n]\to 0$ and $H^{1}_{\acute{e}t}(K(X),\mu_{n})\cong K(X)^{*}/K(X)^{*n}$.
By snake lemma, $f$ is injective if and only if $\mathrm{Pic}(X)[n]\to K(X)^{*}/K(X)^{*n}/(\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*}/\Gamma(X,\mathcal{O}_{X})^{*n})$ is injective
I think the map should be this: Given a $n$-torsion line bundle, we can construct a $n$-th cyclic cover of $X$, it will induce a $n$-th cyclic extension of $K(X)$. So if line bundle map to $1$, it should be trivial line bundle. Thus $f$ should be injecitve.
Am I correct? It seems this is not a rigorous. Can you give a rigorous proof?
Also, if this is true, it seems this is also true when $X$ is just a locally factorial variety. Am I right?

Crossposted at MO.
